# Why does this regex not match this text?

Tags: c#, regex

Why does the following regular expression not match this text?

```
Text: Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei "C:\TEMP\ExchToPlanSyncAppointments.log" zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.
regex: Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei "([\w\s[:punct:]]+)" zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.
```

Comment: what's your code? it's relevant to see whether you escaped properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# regexes, `[:punct:]` is not interpreted as something special, so you are defining a character range that includes ':' and the letters in "punct".

Try `([\w\s:\.\\]+)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

See M42's, or use an @, as in `string meh_regex = @"\w\w\w";`.